# Android: How to set a blurred bitmap as background in all activities?

Tags: java, android

I'm blurring a bitmap and setting it as background image in an activity. How to set it as background in all activities? I can blur it in a singleton class method and access it anywhere but how do I define the singleton object globally( i.e. in all activities). I don't want to run blur algorithm just once.

Comment: your blur image will remain same or you have multiple images?

Comment: Simply define a style, and apply it to all activities. That way you won't have to make changes in each and every activity.xml again to change a new wallpaper.

Comment: I've already defined the style. I need to blur the whichever image picked by theme and apply it in all activities